# CSS Counter is off when "leaving child scope"

Tags: css, css-counter

Don't know the correct way to describe the issue, so here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8qmv4zax/1/) instead.

The problem here is that numbering for `Para 1.3` and `Para 1.4` is off: the `para` counter does not "reset" when it "leaves" the scope of a nested `<section>` tag.

```css
body { counter-reset: chapter 0; }

section { counter-reset: para 0; }

h2:before {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  content: counter(chapter) ". ";
}

section p:before {
  counter-increment: para;
  content: counter(chapter) "." counters(para, ".") ". ";
}
```

```html
<h2>Chapter 1</h2>

<section>
  <p>Para 1.1</p>
  <p>Para 1.2</p>
  
  <section>
    <p>Para 1.2.1</p>
    <p>Para 1.2.2</p>
    
    <section>
      <p>Para 1.2.2.1</p>
      <p>Para 1.2.2.2</p>  
    </section>
  </section>
  
  <p>Para 1.3</p>
  <p>Para 1.4</p>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think it has to do with the HTML structure. `<section>` and `<p>` don't work together because you have to able to include a section inside a p. which is not possible.

use lists instead. because you can include `li` in `ul` and vice-versa . let me know if it helps.

```css
body { counter-reset: chapter 0; }

ul { counter-reset: para ;list-style:none }

h2:before {
  counter-increment: chapter;
  content: counter(chapter) ". ";
}

ul li:before {
  counter-increment: para;

  content: counter(chapter) "." counters(para, ".") ". ";
}
```

```html
<h2>Chapter 1</h2>

<ul>
  <li>Para 1.1</li>
  <li>Para 1.2
   
  <ul>
    <li>Para 1.2.1</li>
    <li>Para 1.2.2

    <ul>
      <li>Para 1.2.2.1</li>
      <li>Para 1.2.2.2</li>  
    </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>

</li>
<li>Para 1.3</li>
<li>Para 1.4</li>

 
</ul>
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Sections can contain paragraphs and other sections, which in turn can contain their own paragraphs and sections, ad nauseum. The reason a paragraph cannot contain a section is because it just doesn't work that way. And why would you recommend marking up a chapter of prose as one gigantic *unordered* list?

Comment: maybe i wasn't clear enough. the `section` with `p` structure doesn't work because you can't make a relationship between a p and a section ( parent-child relationship ) . that's why i used lists ( you can use an OL instead of UL ofc ) . if you look at my structure, inside some `li`s you can find `ul`s . this is not possible with p and section. i gave an alternative solution to the OPs HTML structure.an alternative that achieves what the OP wants. hope i made myself clear now